# Error while installing a .net setup executable locally

Tags: c#, .net, setup-deployment

I have created a setup for my windows application in .NET 2008
After building the same i have the .msi and setup.exe files in my release folder.

The problem i am facing is :
I can install the application using the msi installer files from the shared network folder. But when i copy the installer locally and tried to install it, 
i get the following error: Error reading file.Please Try again.

Anybody having any ideas if there are any properties to set in the installer project.

Regards
Constant Learner

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you can use [Orca](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905) to go through the `.msi` and see if you're having any static references to your development machine within your msi.

Answer (score 0):

The application is a simple windows application without any database associated with it.
Its just a hello world windows application. So i presume its something related to the configuration part of the installation...

Constant Learner